# What's the difference between SkyTeam and Flying Blue?

Tags: airlines, loyalty-programs, skyteam

I am going to reserve a flight with Air France and I just subscribed to the *Flying Blue* program (Air France + KLM).

Is this program the same as *SkyTeam*?

I mean, the miles I earn in Flying Blue are added to the ones that I have accumulated in SkyTeam?

Or should I just buy the Air France flight directly with SkyTeam?

([Here](https://www.flyingblue.com/skyteam/) it seems that Flying Blue belongs to SkyTeam).

Comment: You mention adding the miles to those you "have accumulated in SkyTeam".  Are you accumulating miles with another airline in SkyTeam like Delta, Korean, etc?  If this is the case, then you maybe better giving Air France your frequent flyer number for that airline, so all points stay together.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flying Blue is the airline loyalty programme of Air France, KLM, Air Europa, Kenya Airways, Aircalin, and TAROM. The intention of the programme is to encourage you to spend more money with these airlines [instead of with their competitors], in exchange for certain benefits.

SkyTeam is an airline alliance that includes all of the airlines above, plus several more. The point of the alliance is to offer you, the traveller, better connectivity when far away from your usual airline. For instance when you are travelling inside North America, you cannot travel on Air France. Instead you will probably travel on Delta, which is another SkyTeam member. You may earn miles into Flying Blue and have your Flying Blue status respected by other airlines in SkyTeam.

Flying Blue has a currency (air miles) which are accumulated on these airlines, and their partners. It also has a status system that entitles the member to various benefits, such as access to an airline lounge or fast track through security, when travelling on SkyTeam airlines.

Miles accrued into other programmes cannot be merged into Flying Blue, even if those programmes are also in SkyTeam. If you earn miles into Delta's programme, you cannot transfer them across. The programmes are separate. However, you can earn Flying Blue miles when travelling on Delta, and you can use your air miles to buy Delta flights, because Delta are in SkyTeam. You simply need to give your Flying Blue number to Delta when you buy your flight or when you check in.

You cannot buy flights directly from SkyTeam. They are a marketing organization only.

There are two other airline alliances, oneworld and Star Alliance. In general airlines tend to cooperate with fellow airlines in their alliance and compete with other airlines, but this is a rule of thumb and should not be applied too rigorously.

Comment: Thanks. So can I use my Flying Blue account to reserve flights from Skyteam companies and accumulate miles in a unique "wallet"?

Comment: @mgiordi Yes that's right. For specific information, see https://www.flyingblue.com/partners/airlines.html. You will see that you usually get the most miles from Air France or KLM flights, and dirt cheap flights on some partners don't earn any miles, but there are exceptions.

Comment: @Calchas regarding this topic, I have a specific question. I read that [Skimiles](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/skymiles.html) is the specific miles program of Delta Airlines. If I travel with Delta, my miles will go in which program? Skimiles or FlyingBlue (knowing that Delta is a partner of FlyingBlue)?

Comment: @Mattia that is up to you. If you give your SkyMiles number, the miles go to SkyMiles. If you give your Flying Blue number, the miles go to Flying Blue.

Comment: @Mattia, it's worth noting (in case it's not obvious) that if you're a member of both programs then you should use the same one whenever you have the choice. That way you'll collect more points and get status faster.

Answer (score 2):

**SkyTeam** is an alliance of airlines; members cooperate to make it easier for passengers to fly with other alliance members, for example by codesharing, checking baggage through to one's final destination, and so on.

**SkyPriority** is the label for a group of benefits such as priority check-in and boarding awarded to passengers who are members of alliance airlines' frequent flyer programs. If you have sufficiently high tier in a SkyTeam member's frequent flyer program--such as Flying Blue--you'll automatically receive SkyPriority benefits. SkyPriority is not a frequent flyer program, so you can't enroll in it directly.